# Shorter condition in the filter pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, multiple-conditions, pipes-filters

I have a pipe, that filter dates of clients. Now it looks like:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(clients: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if(!clients) return [];
    if(!searchText) return clients;

    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    return clients.filter( it => {
      if (it.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)) {
        return it.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
      }
      if (it.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)) {
        return it.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
      }
      if (it.street.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)) {
        return it.street.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
      }
      if (it.city.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)) {
        return it.city.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
      }
      if (it.zipCode.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)) {
        return it.zipCode.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
      }
      if (it.country.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)) {
        return it.country.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
      }
      if (it.email.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)) {
        return it.email.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
      }
      if (it.phone.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)) {
        return it.phone.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

But I understend, that the condition can be written shorter. Please, tell me, how can I do it?..

Comment: are these _all_ the properties in client object? you can just go through the Object values

Comment: Angular does not recommend building pipes with heavy operations like this. That's why they didn't implement a filter pipe themselves. Check this https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shorter way to write the condition:

```
return clients.filter(it => 
    it.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
    it.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
    it.street.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
    it.city.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
    it.zipCode.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
    it.country.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
    it.email.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
    it.phone.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this way

```
return clients.filter(function (item: any) {
    for (let property in item) {
      if (item[property] === null) {
        continue;
      }
      if (item[property].toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchText)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
```